# Who pays for the L1 gas costs of ZK-rollups?

Tags: gas, goerli, rollups

I have deployed the same smart contract on both the Goerli Testnet and the Polygon zkEVM Testnet. When I execute the same interaction, it costs the same amount of gas on both networks (as expected), in this case 446,519 gas. On the Goerli Testnet, that's it. However, on the Polygon zkEVM Testnet, this transaction is put in a batch together with other transactions and its validity proof is sent to the Goerli Testnet. Following the transaction on the block explorer, I can eventually reach the block that is submitted to the Goerli Testnet. I can also see that this particular block has a gas usage of 499,809.

My question is who pays for this gas cost on the L1? I'd expect the gas cost on the L2 to be increased slightly, so all the users together cover this cost. However, I pay the exact same amount of gas on the L2 as I do for the same interaction on the L1, so that can't be it.